# GDB x/i get wrong address

Tags: gdb

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("Hello world");
    return 0;
}
```

I was using GDB to debug this program, after running several `si` command,

```
gdb-peda$
[----------------------------------registers-----------------------------------]
...
[-------------------------------------code-------------------------------------]
   0x4003ec:    add    BYTE PTR [rax],al
   0x4003ee:    add    BYTE PTR [rax],al
   0x4003f0:    push   QWORD PTR [rip+0x200c12]        # 0x601008
=> 0x4003f6:    jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x200c14]        # 0x601010
 | 0x4003fc:    nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]
 | 0x400400 <printf@plt>:   jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x200c12]        # 0x601018
 | 0x400406 <printf@plt+6>: push   0x0
 | 0x40040b <printf@plt+11>:    jmp    0x4003f0
 |->   0x7ffff7dee870 <_dl_runtime_resolve_avx>:    push   rbx
       0x7ffff7dee871 <_dl_runtime_resolve_avx+1>:  mov    rbx,rsp
       0x7ffff7dee874 <_dl_runtime_resolve_avx+4>:  and    rsp,0xffffffffffffffe0
       0x7ffff7dee878 <_dl_runtime_resolve_avx+8>:  sub    rsp,0x180
                                                                  JUMP is taken
[------------------------------------stack-------------------------------------]
...
[------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
Legend: code, data, rodata, value
0x00000000004003f6 in ?? ()
```

When i tried to show the instructions in `*0x601010`, i got an error, because GDB was using the wrong address (`0xfffffffff7dee870`), however, when using `x/g` command, the address (`0x00007ffff7dee870`) is correct.

```
gdb-peda$ x/4i *0x601010
   0xfffffffff7dee870:  Cannot access memory at address 0xfffffffff7dee870
gdb-peda$ x/g 0x601010
0x601010:   0x00007ffff7dee870
gdb-peda$ x/8xb 0x601010
0x601010:   0x70    0xe8    0xde    0xf7    0xff    0x7f    0x00    0x00
gdb-peda$ x/4i 0x00007ffff7dee870
   0x7ffff7dee870 <_dl_runtime_resolve_avx>:    push   rbx
   0x7ffff7dee871 <_dl_runtime_resolve_avx+1>:  mov    rbx,rsp
   0x7ffff7dee874 <_dl_runtime_resolve_avx+4>:  and    rsp,0xffffffffffffffe0
   0x7ffff7dee878 <_dl_runtime_resolve_avx+8>:  sub    rsp,0x180
```

Can anyone explain the reason?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This: `x/4i *0x601010` is equivalent to `x/4i (long) *(int*)0x601010`. It loads (truncates) integer `0xf7dee870` from memory location `0x601010`, then sign-extends it to long `0xfffffffff7dee870`, and then tries to read instructions at this (bogus) address.

You want: `x/4i *(long*)0x601010` or `x/4i {long*}0x601010`.

Comment: Thanks~ but why GDB use `int *` instead of `long *`? I'm using Ubuntu x86_64.

Answer (score 0):

```
gdb-peda$ x/4i *0x601010
   0xfffffffff7dee870:  Cannot access memory at address 0xfffffffff7dee870
gdb-peda$ x/g 0x601010
0x601010:   0x00007ffff7dee870
```

In the first command, you write `*0x601010` -- that means the contents of the memory at that location.  In the second command, you omit the `*`, which shows that the contents of that memory are indeed what gdb tried to access in response to the first command.

I think what you probably want is `x/4i 0x601010`, or perhaps the `disassemble` command.

Comment: But the instruction is `jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x200c14]        # 0x601010`, so the real address is `*0x601010 == 0x00007ffff7dee870 `, it seems GDB's address `0xfffffffff7dee870` is only wrong in some digits.